# Converting textView to Boolean to avoid: The method putExtra(String, boolean) in the type Intent is not applicable for the arguments

Tags: java, android, string, textview, boolean

I'm getting an error in eclipse stating: The method putExtra(String, boolean) in the type Intent is not applicable for the arguments (String, TextView)

I believe I'll need to change my textView to a boolean however when I attempt to do so - it causes other errors to occur. What is the best way of avoiding this error in a scenario such as this:

```
public class CustomListViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Cmd> {
    Activity context;
    List<Cmd> videos;

    public CustomListViewAdapter(Activity context, List<Cmd> videos) {
        super(context, R.layout.list_item2, videos);

        this.context = context;
        this.videos = videos;
    }

    /* private view holder class */
    private class ViewHolder {
        ImageView imageView;
        TextView txtSuccess;
        TextView txtCmd;
        TextView txtPrice;
    }

    public void run() {

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, ViewVideo.class);
        ViewHolder holder;
        intent.putExtra("videofilename", holder.txtCmd);
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }

    public Cmd getItem(int position) {
        return videos.get(position);
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item2, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.txtSuccess = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.success);
            holder.txtCmd = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cmd);
            holder.txtPrice = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.price);
            holder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
            convertView.setTag(holder);

        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        Cmd cmd = (Cmd) getItem(position);

        holder.txtSuccess.setText(cmd.getVideoName());
        holder.txtSuccess.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                run();
            }
        });
        holder.txtCmd.setText(cmd.getCmd());
        holder.txtCmd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                run();
            }
        });

        holder.txtPrice.setText(cmd.getVideoURL() + "");
        holder.txtPrice.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                run();
            }
        });

        holder.imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                run();
            }
        });
        return convertView;

    }

}
```

Comment: You can only bundle data that's serializable, your textview is a ui element of your previous activity.  To give you proper assistance, what are you trying to do with your textview in the new Intent?  Do you just need the text inside of it?

Comment: you want the text in textview to be passed to a activity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public void run(String txt) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(context, ViewVideo.class);
    intent.putExtra("videofilename",txt);
    context.startActivity(intent);
}
```

and in get view:

```
final  Cmd cmd = (Cmd) getItem(position);
```

and in onclick:

```
run(cmd.getCmd());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
The method putExtra(String, boolean) in the type Intent is not applicable for the arguments (String, TextView)
```

`public Intent putExtra (String name, boolean value)` name is the key and value is a boolean. So it expects a boolean value.

I don't think you want to boolean either. I guess you want to pass the text in textview to another activity

Look @

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html

You can use the `View` object v

```
holder.txtCmd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                TextView tv =(TextView)v;   // cast to textview 
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, ViewVideo.class);
                intent.putExtra("videofilename", tv.getText().toString());
                // use getText to get the text from textview
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

Or you can use `setTag` and `getTag` on the view

Answer (score 0):

The part:

```
ViewHolder holder;
intent.putExtra("videofilename", holder.txtCmd);
```

won't get you anything, holder.txtCmd.getText is not going to return the filename, instead you can pass the file name with the function run(String filename) as a parameter. Then you will be able to pass it directly as text.